# Arduino Micro pro not uploading any code

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I have been programming the arduino micro pro board for a a few weeks now, recently (on all devices I try on) when I upload my code, any code, via Arduino IDE, I get the following error:

```
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
Found programmer: Id = ""; type = 
Software Version = .; Hardware Version = .
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: error: buffered memory access not supported. Maybe it isn't
a butterfly/AVR109 but a AVR910 device?
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.

avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: error: programmer did not respond to command: leave prog mode
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: error: programmer did not respond to command: exit bootloader
```

when I disconnect and re-connect the board, it runs the last code I uploaded to it before this problem occurred.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: It looks like you either fried your programmer, or the PC configuration is messed up.   I'd try uninstalling/reinstalling the programmer driver.  Or try to make it run with another PC to figure out which.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy I have tried running on separate devices, as for reinstalling the drivers, do you mean re installing the ARDUINO-IDE compiler? The reason I ask is I have already done so, however, if that is not what you mean by drivers, how would I go amongst doing that?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using a linux based OS. try removing the package called "modemmanager"

for ubuntu "sudo apt autoremove modemmanager"

IMPORTANT:
if you have already atmepted to upload code to the pro micro multiple times, chances are that the bootloader on the pro micro got corrupted. you will need to use a serial programmer (like a usbasp) to flash a new bootloader to the pro micro

simple tip to check if your bootloader if ok:
observe your pro micro as you plug the micro usb cable into it. 
1 led should light up and stay lit (indicating that the pro micro is getting power)
and another led should flash on and off (unless a led blink is already uploaded to the promicro in which case it will flash on n off)

if anything else happend with the leds (like the 2nd led continously lit) the booloader is probably corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when trying to upload code into Arduino Micro ( Chinese clone ). Spending hours on Google, flashing new bootloader - still nothing. Physical reset and opening COM port with boundrate 1200 doesn't work. Why?

I HAVE ATMEGA168 INSTEAD OF ATMEGA32u4!

Google is telling, that Arduino Micro got Atmega32u4, but my clone got Atmega168! First of all, check what atmega type do you have by lookup on black soldered chip on Arduino. So instead of choose "Arduino Micro" on Arduino IDE menu, i choose Arduino Nano and everything works!